# How do I get the name of a field from within a method using reflection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

I'm experimenting with reflection in c# for the first time (for use in a dev tool I'm building) and I was wondering if someone could help me to access the thing that I'm trying to access?

The code below is the class I'm accessing:

```
[Serializable]
public class MaterialVariantTarget : BaseNode, IMaterialTarget
{
   public MeshRenderer m_Target;
   public void ApplyValue(Material value) => m_Target.material = value;
}
```

The question I want to answer is ***what is the name of the value*** that *ApplyValue()* operate on. So in this example it would be **MeshRenderer.material**

I've broken the problem down into two parts. Accessing **m_Target**'s Type (**MeshRenderer**) and the **.material** property.

The first, I've managed to access:

```
private Type GetTargetComponentType(Type targetNodeType)
{
    foreach (var fieldInfo in targetNodeType.GetFields())
    {
        if (fieldInfo.Name == "m_Target")
        {
            var type = fieldInfo.FieldType;
            return type;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm finding accessing the scond part more tricky. Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if so, how can I do it?

Many Thanks

---

[UPDATE]

So the consensus seems to be that I can't access the contents of the method.

I'm going to have to just resort to writing out the info I need as a string hich can then be read but its not ideal :(

Might I have more options if I were to arrange it as a property get/setter? like this:

```
[Serializable]
    public class MaterialVariantTarget : BaseNode, IMaterialTarget
    {
        public MeshRenderer m_Target;

        private Material m_valueProperty
        {
            get => m_Target.material;
            set => m_Target.material = value;
        }
        
        public void ApplyValue(Material value) => m_valueProperty = value;
}
```

Comment: so `m_Target` can be of different type depending on the class? If it's always of type `MeshRenderer` all you have to do is cast it

Comment: What you are after would require IL decompilation.

Comment: Both `m_Target` and `.material` could be different. So for example I have another one which has `Transform` and `.localPosition`  .

I guess I could just add a const string which explicitly lists `MeshRenderer.material` but it makes things a bit more brittle as I would need to rememebr to a) fill this out, and b) update it if things changed in the future :(

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with maybe a new approach?

Comment: @RobertJHomewood I don't get why you'd give up on your initial approach without trying out or giving feedback on the suggested answers...

Answer (score 0):

Here's two handy extensions I made to retrieve the value of a field or property of an object based on a name or a type:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object GetPropertyOrFieldByName(this object obj, string nameToSearch)
    {
        foreach (var field in obj.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            if (field.Name == nameToSearch)
            {
                return field.GetValue(obj);
            }
        }

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.Name == nameToSearch)
            {
                return property.GetValue(obj);
            }
        }

        return null;
     }

    public static T GetPropertyOrFieldByType<T>(this object obj) where T : Object
    {
        foreach (var field in obj.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            if (field.FieldType == typeof(T))
            {
                return (T)field.GetValue(obj);
            }
         }

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(T))
            {
                return (T)property.GetValue(obj);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The usage you require could be implemented this way:

```
object target = yourMaterialVariantTarget.GetPropertyOrFieldByName("m_Target");
Material material = target.GetPropertyOrFieldByType<Material>();
material.color = Color.red;
```

Comment: hey, sorry for not getting back to this :)

Comment: While this is a good solution for accessing the value of a field, its unfortunately not quite the data I was trying to access. 

In this solution, I would need to know beforehand that the property I was looking for was of type **Material**.

Comment: The thing I'm stuck on is trying to determine is the name of this field (without knowing its type in advance), based on the class being reflected. So in one case it might be a property of type **Material** called **material** on a **MeshRenderer** component, and in another it might be a property of type **Vector3** called **localPosition** from a **Transform** component. Its also possible that we could be the **localScale** property that I'm trying to access on the same **Transform** component which will also be of type **Vector3** so unfortunately knowing the Type doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: The last thing to note is that I'm not actually after the value of the property. I'm after the name of the property. so my ideal return would be **material** / **localPosition** / **localScale** as a string.

Comment: @RobertJHomewood honestly you should rewrite the question explaining what you intend to achieve and why, and provide some sample cases. As it stands right now it's a tad confusing.